# How to open a link to a folder/file in Finder, not Dired

Tags: org-mode, osx

I used to be able to create links with `open-insert-link` pointing to folders or files. When I clicked on them, I would be redirected to Finder. Lately, they are shown within `Dired`. How to control this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `org-insert-link` (bound to key `C-c C-l` within an org-mode buffer).  Which you would then enter the file name prepend with either `file:`, `file+emacs:` or `file+sys:`.  Within an org-mode buffer `C-c C-o` (`org-open-at-point`) opens the link, or Mouse Click which results in `org-open-at-mouse`.  In my testing only the `file+emacs:` link is opened within an emacs' `dired` buffer.  What is the value of your link?  For example:

`[[file:/users/Shared]]`

Also, take a look at `org-open-file` and `org-file-apps`.

Update: Check MacOS `System Preferences` -> `Security and Privacy`:

- Under `General` tab it might be asking you to accept Emacs.
- Under `Privacy` tab check that `Automation` has *Emacs* listed with the various applications.  I see `Finder`, `System Events.app`, `Safari`, `Mail.app`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I use either [[file:/users/Shared]] or [[file+emacs:/users/Shared]], and click on them, I get the dired buffer, not the Finder app.